# Display dynamically informations in a Symfony layout

Tags: symfony, layout

I have a layout included in another one that display my menu. The labels of my menu items need to be dynamic (like the unread messages number of a mailbox). Then I did this :

```
<a href="{{ path('mypath',{'etat': '2' }) }}">My orders</a>
(
    {{ render(controller('MyController', {'etat':2})) }}
    <span style="color:red">with {{ render(controller('MyController', {'etat':2})) }} in late</span>
)
```

I would like to display labels according to the number that return my controller. I don't know how to get it in a variable.

Comment: The code that you posted doesn't seem complete. Is this supposed to be controller code or Twig code?

Answer (score 0):

When rendering your template in your controller

`return $this->render('twig_template_name.html.twig', array('variable_name' => $variable);`

you pass a variable to the twig template in the array of options as I showed. Your code

`{{ path('mypath',{'etat': '2' }) }}`

prints a path defined in the routing.yml under the 'mypath' section and ends up adding a GET request variable to the link ('?etat=2'), if 'mypath' showed an absolute route 'www.website.com/yourpath',

`{{ path('mypath',{'etat': '2' }) }}` would produce 'www.website.com/yourpath?etat=2', which would send your controller for a route /yourpath/{etat} a variable etat with a value of 2 so all you need to do now is change 2 with an actual dynamic value which you receive from another controller.

I am not sure what etat is but lets say it's an article and it has it's id, you have a blog page with lots of articles and the controller that prints them all out sends an array of articles to the twig template, on your twig template you do something like:

```
{% foreach article in articles %}
    {{ article.title }}
    {{ article.story }}
    <a href="{{ path('single_story_url',{'id': article.id } }}">read more</a>
{% endforeach %}
```

And you end up something like:

Catchy Title

Awesome story about code without bugs and where deadlines depend on how creative and well designed and implemented the solutions are

[read more]

and you ofcourse click on "read more" and end up on the url ~/article/2 because the article had an id of 2, your controller for that url receives a variable id in the request, you do a `$id = $_GET['id'];` and grab the article from the repository and send it to the template.

Hopefully this answered your question, I am very tiered so forgive me if i was confusing which I surely was.

Comment: Then I need to create another template ? Finally, I will have my layout that call my controller that call a template displayed in my layout ?

Comment: first controller renders the template where you use your code: `<a href="{{ path('mypath',{'etat': '2' }) }}">My orders</a>
(
    {{ render(controller('MyController', {'etat':2})) }}
    <span style="color:red">with {{ render(controller('MyController', {'etat':2})) }} in late</span>
)` and the link produced by the path() twig function will create a link with a get parameter, calling a controller from twig is something I don't think is possible as you tried.